# Browser support for eTags

Tags: cross-browser, etag, browser-support

I'm working on getting my site to support the eTag/If-None-Match browser cache, but I'm not sure which browsers do/don't support it. Can anyone point me to a list? I can't imagine it's universal, but I haven't found anything that supports that claim.

cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If-None-Match was Specified in HTTP 1.1 (June 1999):

- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

According to Wikipedia:

> By March 1996, pre-standard HTTP/1.1 was supported in Arena, Netscape 2.0, Netscape Navigator Gold 2.01, Mosaic 2.7, Lynx 2.5, and in Internet Explorer 3.0. End user adoption of the new browsers was rapid. In March 1996, one web hosting company reported that over 40% of browsers in use on the Internet were HTTP 1.1 compliant. That same web hosting company reported that by June 1996, 65% of all browsers accessing their servers were HTTP/1.1 compliant. The HTTP/1.1 standard as defined in RFC 2068 was officially released in January 1997. Improvements and updates to the HTTP/1.1 standard were released under RFC 2616 in June 1999.

In my experience, all browsers in popular use, IE5.5+, Safari, Chrome, Opera, and Firefox, all support the ETag/If-None-Match headers.

However, there are some other headers which will stop these browsers from respecting the etag... so if it's not working for you, I'd carefully examine the other headers being sent back to the client when they request a resource.

Do you have any particular reason for asking the question? Maybe if you had a specific instance you were having an issue with, we could look at the other headers?

But these headers have been around for a long time, and they are a key caching mechanism used widely around the net.

Comment: It's not a problem I'm running into yet. I'm generating dynamic asset files on a per user basis and my plan is to cache them locally so they don't need to be regenerated every time the user needs the file. So it sounds like I could implement an ETag/If-No-Match solution and I would be fine for all the major browsers, correct?

Comment: Yes. I have some large javascript files that change once in a while ~1MB) and I use the etag to save the bandwidth - and I've never run into any browser that doesn't support it.

Comment: @Pacerier, I highly doubt that's the case. If you have HTTP request/response logs that back up what you're saying, please post a new answer and leave me a comment on this answer so I can take a look at it, because I'd be very interested to see such behavior.