# Why would Chrome and IE never send If-None-Match while other browsers do?

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, google-chrome

I'm currently sending the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 2929
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 19 Jul 2012 15:29:18 GMT
ETag: "3e34180212ee59fee7e8e4cc512552e5"
```

Then on subsequent requests I want all browsers to send a `If-None-Match` header with the contents of `ETag` so that I can respond with 304 if necessary. Firefox, Safari, and Opera will all send back the ETag but Chrome and Internet Explorer will not. Is there some header combination or missing value that is causing Chrome and IE to ignore the ETag?

If I set `Last-Modified` then they will all send `If-Modified-Since` but I need to be using ETags.

Comment: Fixed ? i have the same error

Comment: I am using Chrome 62.0.3202.94, having the same problem too. I have already made sure 'disable cache' is not checked in the 'developer tools'.

Answer (score 0):

According to this SO Q&A - [Browser support for eTags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247761/browser-support-for-etags) - Chrome should respect the ETag.

However as the author says: "However, there are some other headers which will stop these browsers from respecting the etag... so if it's not working for you, I'd carefully examine the other headers being sent back to the client when they request a resource."

Is it possible that the "Date" header is causing a problem/conflict with the ETag?